# Vimeo API searching query returning mixed matches

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to implement a search all tags from this user by creating long named tags that won't ever be seen in the titles/descriptions of videos.

Tags like: "This_stuff_right_here_tag"
Then I'm searching like this https://api.vimeo.com/users/xxxx/videos?per_page=40&query=This_stuff_right_here_tag

It works for a bunch of tags but there are these two that are returning a bunch of other different stuff.
Is the search query being dismembered by the Vimeo's backend to get more results matching any of the words or something ? Why does it work with the other searches ?

Comment: Do you mean if you search with one of two specific tags, videos not tagged by those strings show up in the results? Can you send us the exact tags?

Comment: Hi, yes, that's what we are experiencing, I created a ticket to have this checked, and already sent the tags used for your teammate to check.

Comment: Cool, thanks! This is likely a bug, and we will investigate further.

Comment: Hey, I agree with that it is probably a bug, although the answer I got from your team is that the query will not search the tags. Which doesn't explain how it works well for all the other tag options we have been using. Please if you can take a look at this ticket and get back to me as well it would be much appreciated. https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/requests/3013965